# Strange behavior of async wait from console app to asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, async-await, console-application

I have the following method that method with many wait calls mainly like

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<xxxx>> LoadMessageAsync(string Name, bool isError, DateTimeOffset startTime, DateTimeOffset endTime)
    {
        return await BaseTable.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy(typeof(xxxxxxxxxxxxx))
            .SelectManyAsync(async MessageId =>
            {
                return await Session
                    .CqlSelect<xxxxxxxxxxxxx>()
                    .Where(nameof(xxxxxxxxxxxxx.Name), Relation.Equal, Name)
                    .Where(nameof(xxxxxxxxxxxxx.MessageId), Relation.Equal, MessageId)
                    .Where(nameof(xxxxxxxxxxxxx.IsError), Relation.Equal, isError)
                    .Where(nameof(xxxxxxxxxxxxx.QueueMessageId), Relation.GreaterThanOrEqual, CqlFunctions.MaxTimeUuid(startTime))
                    .Where(nameof(xxxxxxxxxxxxx.QueueMessageId), Relation.LessThanOrEqual, CqlFunctions.MinTimeUuid(endTime))
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            });
    }
```

I call it normally from console and return Data . but from asp.net MVC async action it go withoout return any Idea how to solve that

```
var result = await _dataService.LoadMessageAsync(queueName, true, _startDateTimeOffset, _endDateTimeOffset)

if (result != null && result.Any())
        {
        }
```

I even tried `.ConfigureAwait(true);`

Comment: Why do you need async for already asynchronous ASP.NET?

Comment: `but from asp.net MVC async action it go withoout return ` -> what do you mean with this? Can you point out in the code where it does not run to?

Comment: @VMAtm async/await still has a useful place in ASP.Net, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573184/deep-understanding-of-async-await-on-asp-net-mvc and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx.

Comment: Where does `.SelectManyAsync` come from? If it is **not** defined as taking a `Func<T, Task>` your `async` lambda will not work as you'd expect!